# Get Tweets by LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to get tweets from Twitter but it's not working with me, here is the code:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
            {

                CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore()
                {

                    ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***"],
                    ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***"],
                    AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***"],
                    AccessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["***"]

                }

            };

var context = new TwitterContext(auth);
var tweets =
    from tw in context.Status
    where
        tw.Type == StatusType.User &&
        tw.ScreenName == "***"
    select tw;
// handle exceptions, twitter service might be down
try
{
    // map to list
    tweets
        .Take(3)
        .Select(t =>
            new Tweets
            {
                //Username = t.ScreenName,
                //FullName = t.User.Name,
                TweetText = t.Text,
                //FormattedText = ParseTweet(t.Text)
            })
        .ToList();
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

every time it fail when I'm trying to read the tweets, the exception is

```
LinqToTwitter.TwitterQueryException: Bad Authentication data
```

But I'm sure that the credentials are correct.

and also is it possible to read the posts of another twitter account? like a company account or a celebrate account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Twitter is async, so you should change your query like this:

```
var tweets =
    await
    (from tw in context.Status
     where
        tw.Type == StatusType.User &&
     tw.ScreenName == "***"
     select tw)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Also, hit a breakpoint after instantiating auth and inspect Credentials to make sure you've populated them correctly.